# Activity receive params from service

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I write a service that send broadcast message to activity, but in activity i always get null result (broadcastMessage is null). See the code below.

Service code

```
        Intent i = new Intent("MessageBroadcast");
        i.putExtra("HuaeState", 200);
        sendBroadcast(i);
```

Activity code : when i put a break line below in debug mode i could see the value broadcastMessage  is null

```
         public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String broadcastMessage = intent.getExtras().getString("HuaeState");

         }
```

Comment: is my solution worked out?

Comment: Sorry that your solution did not work, i found out that i have to use getInt() instead of getString() in activity. But, thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason is you are adding integer value into intent and getting as string.

Use **[`getint()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BaseBundle.html#getInt(java.lang.String))**.

```
String broadcastMessage = String.valueOf(intent.getExtras().getInt("HuaeState"));
```

or

```
String broadcastMessage = String.valueOf(intent.getIntExtra("HuaeState", -1)); // Where -1 is default value to indicate that there is something wrong while reading value from intent
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify you code in service like this:

```
    Intent i = new Intent("MessageBroadcast");
    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("HuaeState", 200);
    sendBroadcast(i);
```

and Receiver Like:

```
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
              Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
              int value = bundle.getInt("HuaeState");

       }
```

The Mistake you done is you are setting the values to intent and getting the value from bundle.